# How do I use react hooks to tidy up a functional component when it unmounts (using values from state in the tidy up)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component that saves files to cloud storage and saves a reference to those files to a db. The files are pushed to the cloud as soon as they are selected (for UX reasons). But the db object (referencing the URL of the files), isn't saved until the user clicks save. If the user selects some files, but then changes their mind before clicking save, I want to remove the files when the component unmounts.

I'm struggling to carry this out with `useState` and `useEffect`.

```
const [ files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const onFileAdded = fileURL => {
  setFiles([ ...files, fileURL ])
}

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    files.forEach(f => storageAPI.removeFile(f));
  }
}, []);

const onSave = () => {
  setFiles([]);
}
```

In this scenario the `files` variable in `useEffect` is the initialised value `[]`.

if I pass the `files` variable to `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    files.forEach(f => storageAPI.removeFile(f));
  }
}, [files]);
```

Then the file is deleted whenever the `files` variable is updated.

This can't be an uncommon pattern. I'm tidying up a component when it is unmounted, using values from state.

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useRef().

```js
const [ files, setFiles] = useState([]);
const filesRef = useRef(files);


const onFileAdded = fileURL => {
  setFiles([ ...files, fileURL ])
}

useEffect(() => {
  filesRef.current = files;
}, [files]);


useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    filesRef.current.forEach(f => storageAPI.removeFile(f));
  }
}, []);

const onSave = () => {
  setFiles([]);
}
```

Comment: Wrap callback `onSave` and `onFileAdded` to useCallback();

Comment: That did it. Thanks!